# How to disable echoing out a command with local()?

Tags: fabric

I have a rather long fabric command (it's actually a bash script that's wrapped up in fabric for its automation purposes). Despite it being ugly, it's very functional.

The problem is that when you run that Fabric command, it echos out the whole bash script onto the screen (like it does with other `local(..)` and `run(..)` commands. In this case I'd like to disable that.

But I'd still like to see the script output after it's been run.

Answer (score 2):

Fabric's [`settings` ContextManager](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.settings) can work with `hide(..)` to hide certain aspects of the output. In this case, we want to exclude `running`.. So simply:

```
with settings(hide('running',)):
    local('horrible stuff here')
```

That's tested and working.

Comment: You can make it even shorter using only `with hide('running'):`.